# How can I broadcast asyncio StreamReader to several consumers?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to use aiohttp to make a sort of advanced reverse proxy.

I want to get content of HTTP request and pass it to new HTTP request without pulling it to memory. While there is the only upstream the task is fairly easy: aiohttp server returns request content as `StreamReader` and aiohttp client can accept `StreamReader` as request body.

The problem is that I want to send origin request to several upstreams or, for example, simultaneously send content to upstream and write it on disk.

Is there some instruments to broadcast content of `StreamReader`?

I've tried to make some naive broadcaster but it fails on large objects. What do I do wrong?

```py
class StreamBroadcast:
    async def __do_broadcast(self):
        while True:
            chunk = await self.__source.read(self.__n)
            if not chunk:
                break
            for output in self.__sinks:
                output.feed_data(chunk)
        for output in self.__sinks:
            output.feed_eof()

    def __init__(self, source: StreamReader, sinks_count: int, n: int = -1):
        self.__source = source
        self.__n = n
        self.__sinks = [StreamReader() for i in range(sinks_count)]
        self.__task = asyncio.create_task(self.__do_broadcast())

    @property
    def sinks(self) -> Iterable[StreamReader]:
        return self.__sinks

    @property
    def ready(self) -> Task:
        return self.__task
```

Comment: Do sinks have to be instances of `StreamReader`? Your life would probably be much easier if you used `asyncio.Queue`s instead, and stuffed chunks of data (obtained with `read(8192)` or such) into them. The queues could be limited-capacity to allow for backpressure.

Comment: Yes, backpressure is the thing I need. aiohttp seems can't consume `asyncio.Queue` as source of request body but probably I can use it as synchronization primitive in my custom broadcaster. Thank you for idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've looked through `asyncio` sources and discovered that I should use `Transport` to pump data over a stream. Here is my solution.

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import StreamReader, StreamWriter, ReadTransport, StreamReaderProtocol
from typing import Iterable


class _BroadcastReadTransport(ReadTransport):
    """
    Internal class, is not meant to be instantiated manually
    """

    def __init__(self, source: StreamReader, sinks: Iterable[StreamReader]):
        super().__init__()
        self.__source = source
        self.__sinks = tuple(StreamReaderProtocol(s) for s in sinks)
        for sink in sinks:
            sink.set_transport(self)
        self.__waiting_for_data = len(self.__sinks)

        asyncio.create_task(self.__broadcast_next_chunk(), name='initial-chunk-broadcast')

    def is_reading(self):
        return self.__waiting_for_data == len(self.__sinks)

    def pause_reading(self):
        self.__waiting_for_data -= 1

    async def __broadcast_next_chunk(self):
        data = await self.__source.read()
        if data:
            for sink in self.__sinks:
                sink.data_received(data)
            if self.is_reading():
                asyncio.create_task(self.__broadcast_next_chunk())
        else:
            for sink in self.__sinks:
                sink.eof_received()

    def resume_reading(self):
        self.__waiting_for_data += 1
        if self.__waiting_for_data == len(self.__sinks):
            asyncio.create_task(self.__broadcast_next_chunk(), name='chunk-broadcast')

    @property
    def is_completed(self):
        return self.__source.at_eof()


class StreamBroadcast:
    def __init__(self, source: StreamReader, sinks_count: int):
        self.__source = source
        self.__sinks = tuple(StreamReader() for _ in range(sinks_count))
        self.__transport = _BroadcastReadTransport(self.__source, self.__sinks)

    @property
    def sinks(self) -> Iterable[StreamReader]:
        return self.__sinks

    @property
    def is_completed(self):
        return self.__transport.is_completed
```

Hope once I'll pack it to pip module.